# Xmlns to a Class Within a Project Folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to have a namespace in my view which references a ViewModel class. I can reference the folder containing the ViewModels:

```
 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
```

But how do I get to a specific class within that folder? i.e.

```
xmlns:articlevm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels.ArticleViewModel"
```

Essentially I want to reference a type in a HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type articlevm:ArticlesList}"
```

Comment: It is meant for only for namespace. What is ArticlesListin the ViewModel?

Comment: It's "clr-namespace" not "clr-type".  The xmlns becomes a pseudonym for the namespace.  For the `MyNamespace.MyTypeName` class, you would construct a `xmlns:whatever="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`  Now "whatever" represents the "MyNamespace" namespace.  So `MyNamespace.MyTypeName` now maps to `whatever:MyTypeName`.  Is that the misunderstanding??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that "Project Folders" are simply a design time construct which *default* to how your `namespace` is constructed. What you're actually looking for the is the `namespace`, not the Project Folder. This can be important since it is not only fully possible to place a `class` within a `namespace` that doesn't correspond to the folder it's in, the folders also simply don't exist after compilation.

As pointed out by exmaple, the `xmlns` refers to a `namespace` - actually referring to that class involves `ns:Class` within the code. think of `xmlns` as similar to a `using` directive.

If you're trying to reference a subclass (a `class` defined inside of another `class`) you use a `+` - so if `ArticleList` is a `class` within `ArticleViewModel`

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
...
vm:ArticleViewModel+ArticleList
```

If you're referencing a `namespace` from another assembly, you'll need to add that to the `xmlns` - thus

```
xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels;assembly=MyApp"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:sometext.ViewModel"
```

.
.
.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```